# Ionic App: Received memory warning. Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I build an app with ionic framework, you can download from here https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mdz-diario/id1087454519?ls=1&mt=8

When you scroll to the bottom and then you navigate to differents pages and tabs the app is terminated unexpectedly, and when I debug the app I read on the console the next message:

2016-04-24 19:29:08.524 [683:210647] Received memory warning.
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

The console do not log any thing more, and I don't have more information to share.

Someone, maybe have experience with this kind of problems can help me to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could probably (if you are in a hurry) disable ionic cache between tabs/pages. Maybe that could give you the upper hand while you think in another way to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks Seba. on the routes.. i change the cache flag to false, and works properly.

Comment: Hello Seba, I'm facing the same terminated due to memory issue using ionic iOS app, can you please give me small example.